# How to use multiple dtd files in a single xul?

Tags: firefox-addon, dtd

In my firefox addon, I have a few `!ENTITIY`s that I want to put in a "global.dtd" file.  Then, in all of my .xul files, I want to access both that global.dtd as well as that .xul file's particular .dtd file.

Thus, for code1.xul, I would load code1.dtd and global.dtd.
Then, for code2.xul, I would load code2.dtd and global.dtd.

Thus, I could assure the same strings to be used in the global.dtd.

Can I do this?  How do I write the definition?
You can't put two doctypes.

```
<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://myaddon/locale/global.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE overlay SYSTEM "chrome://myaddon/locale/code1.dtd">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a parameter entity in any DTD that you want to use `global.dtd` in.

For example, you would add this to `code1.dtd` and `code2.dtd`:

```
<!ENTITY % global SYSTEM "global.dtd">
%global;
```

You'll have to adjust the SYSTEM identifier to point to the location of `global.dtd`.

Comment: So I have to import each entity separately, and cannot import the entire file?

Comment: @BGM - Using the parameter entity, you are importing the entire file. Basically the entity reference `%global;` gets replaced with the entire contents of `global.dtd`.

Comment: By Golly, that's it!  Thanks a bushel!

Answer (score 2):

You can also can import multiple DTDs in the same XUL file. It looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE some_name [
  <!ENTITY % firstDTD SYSTEM "chrome://extension/locale/first.dtd">
  %firstDTD;
  <!ENTITY % secondDTD SYSTEM "chrome://extension/locale/pref/second.dtd">
  %secondDTD;
]>
```